# c++: Private constructor means no definition of that classes objects inside headers?

Tags: c++, static-members, private-constructor

Yet another question, go me!...
Anyway, I have 2 classes with private constructors and static functions to return an instance of that class.
Everything was fine, I have a main.cpp file where I managed to get hold of my gameState object pointer, by doing:

```
gameState *state = gameState::Instance();
```

But now I seem to have a problem. For the sake of convenience, I wanted both the gameState instance and a actionHandler instance to retain a copy of the pointer to each other. So I tried to include in each other's header files:

```
gameState *state;
```

and

```
actionHandler *handler;
```

This however, doesn't seem to work... I get "error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'" errors on both of those lines... Can you not define variables of a certain classe's in the header if that class has a private constructor? Or is the problem something else?
OR maybe it is because the pointer to teh instance is stored as a static member?

EDIT: Thanks guys! It's amazing the amount of c++ knowledge I'm getting these last couple of days.. awsome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you need to add a forward declaration of the opposite class to each class's header file. For example:

```
class actionHandler;

class gameState
{
private:
    actionHandler *handler;

    ...
};
```

and:

```
class gameState;

class actionHandler
{
private:
    gameState *state;

    ...
};
```

Comment: You don't need forward declarations in both headers.  You can have one `#include` the other.

Comment: Yes, but for compilation times, if you can get away with it, it's better to use forward declarations rather than including the whole class file wherever possible.

Answer (score 4):

Its not because the private constructor.

Its because you have a circular dependency. So when you try to compile class A, you need to compile class B, which needs compiled class A, and so on.

Try a forward declaration.

In the header  file where gameState is defined

```
class actionHandler;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem has nothing to do with the private constructors. In a given translation unit (.cpp file and all included .h files), the C++ compiler doesn't recognize the identifier for a class until the class is declared. This poses a problem when two classes contain members that refer to each other. The solution is called a "forward declaration", which is just the class name, but no body. It may look something like this in your case:

== gameState.h ==

```
...
// Note no #include for "actionHandler.h" (but there would be in gameState.cpp)

class actionHandler;

class gameState
{
  actionHandler *handler;
  ...
};
...
```

== actionHandler.h ==

```
...
#include "gameState.h"

// No forward declaration needed.

class actionHandler
{
  gameState* state;
  ...
};
...
```